# no-sql database for document sizes over 32 MB?

Tags: php, python, mongodb, size, limit

I need `python` and `php` support. I am currently using `mongodb` and it is great for my data (test results), but I need to store results of a different type of test which are over 32 MB and exceed mongo limit of 16 MB.

Currently each test is a big python dictionary and I retrieve and represent them with `php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store up to 16MB of data per MongoDB BSON document (e.g. using the pymongo Binary datatype). For arbitrary large data you want to use GridFS which basically stored your data as  chunks + extra metadata. When you using MongoDB with its replication features (replica sets) you will have kind of a distributed binary store (don't mix this up with a distributed filesystem (no integration with local filesystem).